# DatePicker jquery and simple_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to use the Jquery date picker in my simple_form.

I have a field

```
<%= simple_form_for @customer, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
<%= render "shared/error_messages", :target => @customer %>
  <%= f.input :start_lease_date, :as => :text %>
<% end %>
```

I have installed the Jquery-ui gem, I have added the require option in my application.js

```
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
```

I have also added the require in my application.css

```
 *= require jquery.ui.datepicker
```

I also added the customer.js.coffee file with the following

```
jQuery ->
$('#customer_start_lease_date').datepicker
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
```

However, my Start_lease_date field is still not showing a datepicker

Comment: might seem obviuos but have you included //= require jquery in your application/js

Comment: can you update your question with your application.js file (just the top part) with require etc

Answer (score 2):

I guess the following will work

```
<%= f.input :start_lease_date, :as => :text, 
            :input_html => { :class => 'date_picker' }  %>
```

or

```
 <%= f.input :start_lease_date, :as => :date_picker %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im going to take a wild guess and say you haven't got Jquery running/installed. Jquery-UI depends on Jquery for it to work

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your gem file...

```
group :assets do
  # ...
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end
```

...and this to your app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
```